# Java add component inside JPanel using JFrame Form

Tags: java

I'm working with my code that will decode a QR Code through the use of webcam. I've seen a project related to this and I used it. I saw it at `https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-qrcode`

So, I created a JFrame Form then I dragged-in the JPanel at the center of the form. I want the webcam to display inside the centered-JPanel. Something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MqsrxdM.png]

I've used this code below but gives me a wrong layout. Here's the screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/udBCQJ8.png]

```
public class main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Webcam webcam = null;
    private WebcamPanel panel = null;
    private JTextArea textarea = null;

    public main() {
        initComponents();

        Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();
        webcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0);
    webcam.setViewSize(size);

        WebcamPanel lab1 = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        add(lab1 = new WebcamPanel(webcam));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A FlowLayout displays labels on a line from left to right.

> I want the webcam to display inside the centered-JPanel.

The easiest way to center a component on a panel is the use the GridBagLayout:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
panel.add(someComponent, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Now "someComponent" will be centered horizontally and vertically in the space available to the panel.